# Trying to forward domain.com/abcd to some different local subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, dns, hosts

In the apache server installation I have a .conf file which forwards all requests from www.domain.com to c:\www\domain.  Now, i'm **trying to forward www.domain.com/abcd to a different subfolder locally (say c:\www\abcd)**. i tried adding another .conf which looked like this.

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.domain.com/abcd
        DocumentRoot "c:/www/abcd"

        ErrorDocument   404 /404.php
        ErrorLog "C:/logs/error.log"
        CustomLog "d:/logs/access.log" common

        <Directory "c:/www/abcd">
                RewriteEngine on
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

        <Location />
          Order deny,allow
          Deny from all
          Allow from all
        </Location>
 </VirtualHost>
```

This doesn't work as intended. When i go to www.domain.com/abcd , I guess its trying to access c:\www\domain\abcd and showing not found error. Is there anyway to solve this issue **without making DNS entries and without making changes to your local hosts file**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution would be to make a symbolic link

```
mklink /D C:\www\domain\abcd C:\www\abcd
```